# MVC: how to post back user selection and respond with PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, pdf-generation, postback

This should be a simple answer, but as I'm new to MVC I don't fully know my way around just yet: I want to respond to the user clicking a link by sending a PDF down to the browser.

- I have a string of IDs on the page that I need to post back to the method so that it can generate the requested content.
- I can build the PDF as a memory stream exposed to the controller.
- I want the user to stay on the same page on which they clicked the link and be presented with the "Save to..." dialog.

Assuming my controller is called *Invoice* and the method is *DownloadInvoice*, what should I put on my view to post the IDs back (string), and how do I respond to this postback?

Can I simply respond with this

```
return new FileStreamResult(generatedInvoice.Stream, "application/pdf");
```

Or do I need to direct the viewer to another view which has the full

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=labtest.pdf");
Response.Buffer = true;
Model.Stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for another view. The `FileStreamResult` should be enough on a controller action (you may want to filter such an action with a `[Post]` attribute).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Oded - please see my comment to the previous post.
Also, I'll be using HttpPost and another custom attribute to ensure it's authorised and came from the same website.

Comment: @awj - What do you mean by `post the user selection back`? You are returning a PDF.

Comment: @Oded - On a page I have a list of checkboxes. The user makes a selection of these checkboxes, and then clicks a link. This selection then needs to be posted back to the server so that the content in the PDF is directed by the user's selection. It's not simply a case of the user requesting the PDF, the the user determines what's _in_ the PDF.

Comment: @awj - I understand that, but surely your controller action takes as parameters the values of the selected checkboxes in order to generate the PDF?

Comment: @Oded - yes, the method accepts a string. But my question is, what method can I use in the view which will allow me to specify a method _and_ an argument? I can think that one solution might be to use jQuery to append the user selection to the URL, _i.e._ /Invoice/DownloadInvoice/[user selection]/, but this is messy and with all the conveniences of MVC, I'm sure there must be an easier way to get the user's selection back to the server.

Comment: @awj - Have you looked at view models? If you are using a strongly typed view and bind the view model to it, your post method can accept the posted view model as a parameter and use those values.

Comment: @Oded - The view is already built on a model. I think the only way to do what you're suggesting would be to modify that view to have a string member, then use something like Html.TextFor(...  - is that what you're suggesting? If so then it seems a little wasteful to add this field to the model (used on more than a few other views) just so that I can create a field to post back. Is there no method which allows me to specify a method and values?

Comment: @Oded - I've managed to do it with Url.Action(...  , using some javascript to append the user selection and mapping the route in global.asax. However, the PDF now opens in the same browser/tab. How can I configure it to prompt the user where to save it without moving the user away from the page in which they initiated the download from?

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you just try it?

```
return new FileStreamResult(generatedInvoice.Stream, "application/pdf");
```

Returning a filestream returns as it say: a file. This does not send any header or anything to the browser to tell it to load up another url.

Comment: Ok, so I could respond using new FileStreamResult(), but how do I post the user selection back? What method is there that I can use that points to a method & controller (although in this case the method is on the same controller) and some sort of object containing the user selection? Pleas bear in mind that I have to use some javascript to determine this user selection and format it.